# Get nlb clusternode HostPriority in .NET

Tags: .net, powershell, nlb

I am trying to get HostPriority of a nlb clusternode with powershell in .net

```
using (RunspaceInvoke invoker = new RunspaceInvoke())
{
    invoker.Invoke("Import-Module NetworkLoadBalancingClusters");
    foreach (PSObject result in invoker.Invoke("Get-NlbClusterNode -NodeName $env:COMPUTERNAME"))
    Console.WriteLine(result.Members["HostID"].Value.ToString());
}
```

This returns nothing.

I loop through all the members on the returned `PSObject`, there is nothing the same compare with whatever you get by running powershell cmdlet.

I also tried `Get_Item` as following with a return type of `Microsoft.NetworkLoadBalancingClusters.PowerShell.Node`.

```
using (RunspaceInvoke invoker = new RunspaceInvoke())
{
    invoker.Invoke("Import-Module NetworkLoadBalancingClusters");
    foreach (PSObject result in invoker.Invoke("Get-NlbClusterNode -NodeName $env:COMPUTERNAME"))
    Console.WriteLine(result.Methods["get_item"].Invoke(0).GetType().ToString());
}
```

but I can't really cast to the Node since I couldn't reference `Microsoft.NetworkLoadBalancingClusters.PowerShell.dll` in the powershell directory, could be that it is a 64 bit dll.

Any ideas what should I do from here?

Comment: I am ditching .NET for PowerShell script now since I can't figure out how to get it to work.